# overcome limitation on cisco 6500 monitor session

Tags: cisco, switch, mirror

Is there any way to overcome the 2 monitor session limitation by upgrading the Sup engine card for 6500 Cisco Switch?

Comment: Are you just talking about local SPAN?  What kind of supervisors are you running?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you cannot do anything to increase the amount of SPANs (monitor-sessions) you can perform simultaneously on a Catalyst6509.  When we previously ran into this problem, we started using VACLs instead and sending the traffic to capture ports.

Comment: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/lan-switching/vlan-access-lists-vacls/89962-vacl-capture.html